# Icons with parameters

Tags: inno-setup

I'm creating a setup and came to a problem.

For the installation to finish I need to run my program because of some complex actions (Import DB from old program, creating new DB, selecting DBs etc) need to take place before installed application can run so I do it thru [RUN] sections

```
[RUN]
Filename: "{app}\Config.exe"; Parameters: "{code:RunAscParams}"; Flags: waituntilterminated 32bit; Description: "Runing config"
```

`Config.exe` creates XML file with some values.

As my application can be used with multiple databases running I need to pass XML to specify config which to run

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My APP"; Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Parameters:"<DBNAME>.xml"
```

As the `DBNAME.xml` is not a fixed name. The name of XML file is something thats is created thru `Config.exe` and depends on database name created.

The problem is that I can not set parameters for `[Icon]` as the section `[Icons]` comes before `[Run]` section.

The question is there a runtime possibility to add icons?

Comment: I believe you could create `<DBNAME>.xml` with `AfterInstall` procedure in `[Code]` section with `Exec` before `[Icons]` section instead of creating it in `[Run]` section.

Comment: If `<DBNAME>` can be changed to any, you could also try to rename `result.xml` to `fixnamed.xml` so the icon parameter could always use same, fix-named parameter. But... that is just a walkaround instead of real solution.

Comment: At the end I used AfterInstall procedure call. Thanks for suggestion